# Adding a top border with multiple non-gradient colors

Tags: css, border

I would like to add a border on top of my footer that's several different colors like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWAWn.png

I looked around and I see examples of adding images, or gradients, or multiple colors for different sides but could't find anything for what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS Gradients for this.

Have a look at the snippet below (*you may change the colors according to your requirements*):

```css
.border-top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(248,80,50,1) 0%, rgba(241,111,92,1) 10%, rgba(241,111,92,1) 10%, rgba(246,41,12,1) 10%, rgba(81,24,240,1) 10%, rgba(81,24,240,1) 23%, rgba(240,24,226,1) 23%, rgba(240,24,226,1) 34%, rgba(39,192,230,1) 34%, rgba(39,192,230,1) 46%, rgba(39,230,52,1) 46%, rgba(39,230,52,1) 58%, rgba(76,82,80,1) 58%, rgba(76,82,80,1) 69%, rgba(173,173,173,1) 69%, rgba(173,173,173,1) 81%, rgba(255,0,21,1) 81%, rgba(255,0,21,1) 91%, rgba(255,204,0,1) 91%, rgba(255,204,0,1) 100%);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="border-top"></div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @KingOfKong It's my pleasure!